# Spring-data dynamic repository creation for Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-4

Good day,

I'm trying to dynamically create spring-data repositories creation and injection for spring 4.

So, I would like to do something like this:

```
public abstract class CRUDService<T extends AbstractEntity> {
@Autowired
private CrudRepository<T, Long> repository;
 ....
}
```

without concrete implementation of CrudRepository for each entity.

Is there any way to implement this just using some of spring core mechanism? (I was trying to implement it using BeanFactoryPostProcessor, but no success).